# GroceryCrud + CodeIgniter change value inside field

Tags: codeigniter, grocery-crud

I'm using GroceryCrud for save data. User register is from website itself. When select their sex, i'm saving 1 for male, 2 for female. Database field is tinyint. So problem is, when admin view their data from backend, it's obvious 1 or 2 will appear on Sex field. How to change it into male, female depending on value?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [callback_column](http://www.grocerycrud.com/documentation/options_functions/callback_column) for this.

In your case you can do:

```
public function webpages()
{
  $c = new grocery_CRUD();

  $c->set_table('users');
  $c->columns('firstname','lastname','sex','age');

  $c->callback_column('sex',array($this,'_callback_sex'));

  $output = $c->render();
  $this->_view_output($output);
}

public function _callback_sex($value, $row)
{
    if ($value == '2') {
        return 'male'
    } elseif ($value == '1') {
        return 'female';
    } else {
        return "-";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. But only when see grid. How it implement on edit?

Comment: You can use the field_type method. More specifically you can use the dropdown http://www.grocerycrud.com/documentation/options_functions/field_type#dropdown-field

Answer (score 0):

For edit view use this call back function:

```
$c->callback_edit_field('sex',array($this,'_callback_sex_edit'));

public function _callback_sex_edit($value){
    switch ($value) {
        case "1":
            return '<input type="radio" name="sex" value="1" checked="checked"/> Female 
            <input type="radio" name="sex" value="2" /> Male';
            break;
        case "2":
            return '<input type="radio" name="sex" value="1"/> Female 
            <input type="radio" name="sex" value="2" checked="checked"/> Male';
            break;
        default:
            return '<input type="radio" name="sex" value="1"/>Female 
            <input type="radio" name="sex" value="2"/> Male';
    }

}
```